# Is there a way to combine posts/comment streams?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, praw

In praw, I can create either a `subreddit.stream.comments()` or `subreddit.stream.submissions()`.

For those unfamiliar, the two above praw functions return comments/posts as they come in.

Is there a way to combine the two? I've tried using Python's built-in function `zip` as well as `itertools`'s `zip_longest` but they both only give a result as fast as the posts come in. (Comments are *much* more frequent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
comment_stream = subreddit.stream.comments(pause_after=-1)
submission_stream = subreddit.stream.submissions(pause_after=-1)
while True:
    for comment in comment_stream:
        if comment is None:
            break
        print(comment.author)
    for submission in submission_stream:
        if submission is None:
            break
        print(submission.title)
```

The key is the `pause_after` parameter.

Source:  https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/7vj6ox/can_i_do_other_things_with_praw_while_reading/dtszfzb/

Comment: Probably it would be a good idea to add some kind of sleep in the main loop when none of the two streams returned new items.